# How to define subdocuments of arrays of objects in mongoose?

Tags: mongoose-schema

Here is my example.

I want to create an object that will have an array of this kind of objects:

`{ name, type, pays : [ amount, pay, bonus, multiplier ] }`

Here is part of my schema:

```
symbolsD: [
  {
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    type: [{ type: String, enum: ['line', 'scatter', 'wild', 'wildLineMax', 'bonus', 'lineMultiplier', 'totalWinMultiplier'], required: true, default: 'line' }],
    pays: [{
      amount: { type: Number, required: true },
      pay: { type: Number, required: true },
      bonus: { type: String },
      multiplier: { type: Number }
    }]

  }
]
```

I get an error

```
TypeError: Undefined type `undefined` at array `symbolsD`
```

What is wrong with my schema design?

Answer (score 0):

First thing, If possible change the type to something else. As mongoose Schema has default type attribute to specify the type of your field. So it might create a problem.

Well the reason of your error is - first thing if it is Array of types then you should give some field name on which these property will applied. eg.

```
symbolsD: [
   {
      type: [{
          **typeName** : {
              type: String,
              enum: ['line', 'scatter', 'wild', 'wildLineMax'],
              required: true,
              default: 'line'
          }
      }],
   }
```

]

Or if it is not a array of type then simply remove [] from type.

```
type: {
     type: String,
     enum: ['line', 'scatter', 'wild'],
     required: true,
     default: 'line'
}
```

Hopefully this will help you. Good Luck.